# Non-determinant behavior for empty/missing comments in posts via Facebook feed API

Tags: android

The following Android/Java pseudo-code results in a successful wall/timeline post IF the comment string is non-empty.

```
    params.putString("picture", img_url);
    params.putString("message", comment);
    params.putString("link", link_url);
    params.putString("name", name);
    params.putString("caption", caption);

    facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

If the comment (String type in Java) is null or an empty/blank string, the request returns a successful response but is not posted to the wall. The same behavior occurs if the message parameter is simply omitted.

I thought I could be clever and pass a comment string of "    " or some other piece of whitespace. But in that case, the request actually fails, complaining that the "message param must be non-blank".

This seems like such a blatant failure of the API that I keep trying it again day after day expecting it to get fixed on the back end, but no luck so far.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to put a message on the post.

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this. I see an issue title, beginning with "Non-determinant behavior..." and an issue message, beginning with "The following Android/Java pseudo-code...". Am I missing something?

Comment: A recent update from Facebook resolved this issue, so it was indeed on their end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was simply to wait for Facebook to correct the issue, which they eventually did.